# How to rearrange sections, when using Core Data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sorting, core-data

Is there any way I can rearrange the sections of a Table View that uses Core Data, without using a Sort Descriptor?
The kind of sort I need is not alphabetical, and it'll vary on time (I have read that, using Core Data, you can't use custom selectors for a sort descriptor, so the default ones doesn't help me).

I have a method that gets called when a "section reordering" should happen, and I wonder if there's some kind of "index vector" I can modify, so the sections get ordered by that index, or something similar.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

**1**
Anything you want to order in core data (and, by extension, using a `NSFetchedResultsController`) you will need to somehow model in your data and use sort descriptors.

You state (but do not explain) that "the default [sort descriptor] doesn't help" you. I suppose that means that with the data contained in your model is not sufficient to do the reordering. In this case you would have to introduce a new attribute to the entity in question. That might sound like too much effort, but often it is not that bad.

**2**
You can change the `datasource` of your table view from the fetched results controller to your own scheme (e.g. with arrays). Of course, there are memory implications, but this might just be the easiest way.

**EDIT**
After you restated the problem (circular vector sorting) here is a suggestion: you can use `sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:` to construct a sort descriptor that delivers exactly the result you want. (**warning: untested code**)

```
int centerNumber = 2;  // or whatever your method returns
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor 
     sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" 
                 ascending:YES 
                  comparator:^(int a, int b) {
   NSComparisonResult r;
   if (a == b) r = NSOrderedSame;
   else if (a == centerNumber) r = NSOrderedAscending;
   else if (b == centerNumber) r = NSOrderedDescending;
   else if (abs(a-c) == abs(b-c))
      if (a<b) r = NSOrderedDescending;
      else r = NSOrderedAscending;
   else 
      if (abs(a-c) > abs(b-c)) r = NSOrderedAscending;
      else r = NSOrderedDescending;
   return r;
}];
```

Let me know if it works.

**EDIT 2**
If you need NSNumber (which is how your data is stored most likely), maybe this works:

```
...^(id x, id y) {
   int a = [x intValue];
   int b = [y intValue];
   ...
}...
```

**Final Edit**

If the comparator does not work, insert `NSComparisonResult` as the result type:

```
...comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id x, id y){....
```

Comment: Mmh, maybe I'm missing something about the sort descriptors. I have one attribute in my model that stores a number (1 to 5), and I want to order them beginning with the one indicated by the method that fires when a reordering is needed. For example, if the method says "2", I want the sections to be ordered as "2, 3, 1, 4, 5". That is, first, the one the method says, and then the +1 and -1 ones, the +2 -2, etc., in a "circular vector" way. Could this be done using the default sort descriptors?

Comment: It can be done by using a custom comparison selector. See my edit.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to set the fetched results controller to work with a request with this sort descriptor, but it does not execute the comparator! I've tested the comparator outside this, and it works, and if I put an NSLog inside it, it gets called. However, when setting it as a comparator, it does not get called, the sections doesn't get reordered and there's no NSLog in the console. I'm sure I'm setting the fetched results controller the right way (the "ascending" parameter of the sort descriptor works). Where could be the problem? :S

Comment: Maybe a and b have to be NSNumber rather than int.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I've tried this:
 `^(id a, id b) {
    NSLog(@"Inside block");
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  }`
And the NSLog does not get called. However, if I call `sortedArrayUsingComparator` passing this same block to an array, the array gets sorted, and the NSLog appears.
So I guess Core Data doesn't allow custom comparators...Any ideas on how could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you set the sort descriptors of the fetch request to an array containing this sort descriptor?

Comment: Yes I did. I've been reading other posts and everybody seems to have the same problem here: the comparator block never gets executed. Reading the documentation, it says that Core Data works on another level, not Objetive-C based, and therefore, custom comparators won't work, and you only can use the default ones. I think my workaround will be to add a new attribute to my entity, which will be the index. I'll set it before the refetching, using this sorting algorithm, and then I'll do the fetching, using ascending ordering of this attribute. Hope that works!

Comment: Btw, your algorithm orders the items on the contrary: If the number is 4, should do 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, but it does 4, 2, 1, 3, 5. The first one is ok, but the others are inverted. I'm trying to fix that, but if you want to contribute in the meanwhile... :)

Comment: You are welcome to edit the answer - if the post helped you consider ticking the checkmark. I will keep you updated if I make any experiments with fetch request custom sorting.

Comment: I found a solution: you have to add `NSComparisonResult` as the return type! -- See my edit.